# Use outerclass object in class

Tags: php

I want to use my mysql-object (that is declared out of the class) in a class.
I tried a few things with global and $GLOBAL but nothing seems to work.

The code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("...");

class Tournament {
  public static function AddTournament($...) {
    $mysqli->query("...");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just make your function `mysqli`-dependent? Like `public static function addTournament(mysqli $mysqli,$...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as a parameter and call it:

```
class Tournament {
  public static function AddTournament($mysqli) {
    $mysqli->query("...");
  }
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("...");

Tournament::AddTournament($mysqli);
```